# Javafx TextArea setText method using text files

Tags: javafx, textarea, text-files

Hi I am trying to create a method to be used in the TextArea setText method for javafx.

I am trying to get a method that does this:

```
public static void  setTextArea(String fileName) {

    String line;

    try {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader buffer = new   BufferedReader(fileReader);

        while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            out.println(line);
        }
        buffer.close();
} catch //etc etc
```

but I can't use it in the setText method because it is a void method.
Can anyone help translate this method so it could work in the TextArea setText method?
-Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just pring out the lines to System.out I guess. You have to add up the content of the text file by doing something like this

```
public static void  setTextArea(String fileName) {

String line;
String content;

try {
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
    BufferedReader buffer = new   BufferedReader(fileReader);

    while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
        out.println(line);
        content += line;
    }
    buffer.close();
} catch //etc etc
```

Then you can either return `content` or call `setText(content)` from the TextArea class. If it's a big file, then using `StringBuilder` would probably be a better idea instead of concatenating each line.

Comment: Do you know why in the textbox it starts with "null" then continues with the text?

If it is printed in java's run box it doesn't have null

Answer (score 0):

You will have to get the data from the file and and set the data to textArea..

```
  TextArea txtArea = new TextArea();
  String data = getDataForTextArea(String fileLocation);
  txtArea.setText(data);
public String getDataForTextArea(String fileLocation) {
  InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileLocation);
        if (inputStream != null) {
            int b;
            String txtData = "";
            try {
                while ((b = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
                    txtData += (char) b;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                inputStream.close();
            }
            return txtData;
    }
```

Make sure to check for nullpointerException.